# Samsung keyboard security bug - was patch released?

Tags: samsung, security

Last month, a security flaw affecting the bundled (and unremovable) keyboard app used in many Samsung devices (S4, S5, S6) was announced:

- [New exploit turns Samsung Galaxy phones into remote bugging devices](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/06/new-exploit-turns-samsung-galaxy-phones-into-remote-bugging-devices/)
- [Samsung Mobiles Vulnerable To Keyboard Cracking Attack](http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/06/16/samsung-galaxy-s6-vulnerable-to-cunning-keyboard-cracking-attack/)
- [CVE-2015-4640 - SwiftKey language-pack update vulnerability](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-4640)

Samsung [promised that a fix](http://global.samsungtomorrow.com/information-regarding-the-keyboard-security-issue-and-our-device-policy-update/) would roll out within a few days of June 18th

However,  I haven't seen any announcements that the fix was actually pushed -- how do I confirm that my device received the update?

*Samsung initially reported that they provided a patch to the cell phone carriers, but since carriers are known to be slow to patch phones, especially older models, as far as I know, that patch has not made it out to phones, and it's not clear that it ever well. So Samsung said that they'd push it out directly to users.*